# jQuery fade-in-out animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I need to add a `fade-in-out` transition animation to this ajax loading code. Could someone explain me how to do it please?

JS  :

```
function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');    
    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
         }

       });

     }
```

Comment: Why not use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)?

Comment: You can't fade in or out an ajax function. You can fade DOM nodes in and out, please specify your question better.

Comment: @hellaFont , hello he means when Before ajax call Use fadeIn ,and at the time of success fadeOut.What do u mean cant fadeIn/out?please read http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: @PratikJoshi, I mean that the way his question was phrased made it sound like she/he wanted to fadein/out the ajax function itself rather than a DOM node. Obviously that's not what she/he meant, but she/he should clarify her/his question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `beforeSend()` function of ajax request to `fadeIn()` and in success `fadeOut()`

```
$('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "load_page.php",
    data: 'page=' + url,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#loading').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function (msg) {

        if (parseInt(msg) != 0) {
            $('#pageContent').html(msg);
            $('#loading').fadeOut();
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Just as a sidenote, if the ajax function fails or the returned data isn't exactly zero, you're stuck with the loader.

Comment: "#loading" is the loading bar, what I need to fade is #pageContent, which is the content <div>

Comment: @adeneo , we can add Condition along with Not equal to Zero value.So after testing we can see what are the possible outcomes ,and accordingly if () can be modified

Comment: @user3791817 , then you should clarify HTML in your question.You didnt add HTML ,please add it if u can,to get proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you want to show the effects on success of the ajax result. You may try this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "institutions-filter.action",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg)
    {
        if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
        {
          $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
          $("#pageContent").fadeOut(400, function()
          {
              $("#pageContent").html(msg).fadeIn(400);
          });
        }
    }
});
```